# Multi send transactions are no longer displaying actions

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

Previously on the Gnosis Safe UI, when I proposed a multi-send safe transaction using the `safe-core-sdk` and `safe-service-client`, I was able to see each action associated with that tx.

Now when I send up multi-send tx's, I am not able to see what the actions associated with the transaction are.

Has there been an update to the UI? Or is there anything else that will mean that the multisend tx does not display the associated actions in the UI?

Cheers

Comment: It is related to https://github.com/gnosis/safe-client-gateway/issues/725. We are currently working on improving how to flag dangerous multisend txs. Therefore currently we only show multisend transactions that use `MultiSendCallOnly` (see https://github.com/gnosis/safe-deployments/blob/main/src/assets/v1.3.0/multi_send_call_only.json#L2)

Comment: Ah right. Is there any way to see in the UI what actions make up a transaction in the UI? For example, previously I could see there were 3 actions (transfers with token amounts) in the Gnosis Safe UI for a multisend I had proposed, however now there is no ability to see this. Can you send up some option as part of the proposed transaction that allows this to be shown?

Comment: It will be back soon. If you are just looking for a tool to verify this for yourself you can use https://rimeissner.dev/transaction-decoder/